# Run powershell script using different credentials

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to run a powershell script logged on as a particular user who has no "Script running" permissions. If I wanted to run the script as a different user is it possible to just add the credentials as a parameter to the script?

./Get-Something –computerName SERVER1 –filePath C:\Whatever -credentials ??

Cheers in advance!
(Powershell noob)

Comment: What, pray tell, are the "script running" permissions you refer to?

Comment: i really have no idea myself :S....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath "yourPath\yourScript.ps1" -ComputerName yourServer -Credential Get-Credential
```

Comment: thanks! but how do i get the correct user info using the "-Credential Get-Credential"?

Comment: You can store credential in a variable using
`$cred = Get-Credential "domain\username"`, then use it in `Invoke-Command ... -Credential $cred`. If you need to maintain credential across different powershell session refer to this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/powershell-code-to-store-user-credentials-encrypted-for-re-use/5817

Answer (score 1):

You may also create a Scheduled Task invoking the script with the powershell.exe.

This provides a chance to add parameters and to run the script with elevated rights. You do not Need much code to accomplish this.

Cheers

Oliver