# Any idea how to resolve this powershell error?

Tags: powershell

Please forgive me on this one.

I am extremely new to power shell.

I posted a question here yesterday asking for any assisting with reading contents of iis log programmatically.

No response on that yet.

So, after painstaking googling, I found a Power Shell script that *appears* close to what I am looking for.

When I attempted to execute it, I got the following error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\servername\c$\windows\system32\logfiles\
W3SVC1' because it does not exist.
```

I am reasonably confident that this is more of a permission issue because the path exists.

Does anyone know how to add username and password to the script below?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
#
# Script constants
#

$Server = 'myServer'
$Days = 1

Function Read-IISLog {
  [CmdLetBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)]
      [ValidateScript( { $_ | %{ Test-Path $_ } } )]
    [Alias("FullName")]
    [String[]]$Path
  )

  Process {

    $Path | ForEach-Object {
      $FullPath = (Get-Item $_).FullName
      $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($FullPath, "Open", "Read", "ReadWrite")
      $StreamReader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($FileStream)

      For ($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
        $Line = $StreamReader.ReadLine()
        If ($Line -Match '#Fields: ') {
          $Header = ($Line -Replace '#Fields: ').Split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        }
      }
      Do {
        $Line = $StreamReader.ReadLine()
        If ($Line -NotLike "#*") {
          $Line | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header $Header
        }
      } Until ($StreamReader.EndOfStream)
    }

  }
}

$Output = @{}

$Server | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem "\\$_\c$\windows\system32\logfiles\W3SVC1" -Filter *.log | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days) } |
    Read-IISLog |
    Where-Object { $_."cs-uri-stem" -Match 'ActiveSync' } 
} | Select-Object `
    @{n='FirstSync';e={ [DateTime]::ParseExact("$($_.date) $($_.time)", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $Null) }},
    @{n='LastSync';e={ [DateTime]::ParseExact("$($_.date) $($_.time)", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $Null) }},
    @{n='ClientIP';e={ [Net.IPAddress]($_."c-ip") }},
    @{n='ClientDevice';e={ $_."cs(User-Agent)" }},
    @{n='AuthenticatedUser';e={ $_."cs-username" }},
    @{n='Mailbox';e={ $_."cs-uri-stem".Split("/")[2] }},
    @{n='DeviceId';e={ $_."cs-uri-stem".Split("/")[-1] }},
    @{n='DeviceType';e={ $_."cs-uri-stem".Split("/")[-2] }},
    @{n='SyncCount';e={ 1 }} |
  ForEach-Object {
    If (!$Output.Contains($_.DeviceId)) {
      $Output.Add($_.DeviceId, $_)
    } Else {
      If ($_.FirstSync -lt $Output[$_.DeviceId].FirstSync) { $Output[$_.DeviceId].FirstSync = $_.FirstSync }
      If ($_.LastSync -gt $Output[$_.DeviceId].LastSync)   { $Output[$_.DeviceId].LastSync = $_.LastSync }
      $Output[$_.DeviceId].SyncCount += 1
    }
  }
$Output.Values
```

This is a desperate attempt at resolving this as users are expecting a demo tomorrow.

Comment: Try running your script as a different user who has access to the given path. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569678/run-powershell-script-using-different-credentials

Comment: Access to the `\c$` share requires membership of the local Administrators group on the machine

Comment: If current provider is not `FileSystem`, then you have to qualify your path with provider name: `FileSystem::\\$_\c$\windows\system32\logfiles\W3SVC1`.

Comment: @Harsh, Mathias, PetSerAl, thanks to all of you for your kind responses but how do I incorporate your suggestions into that script, Harsh/Mathias?

Comment: You need to create another powershell script which will invoke your script under given user account with privileges to access the network drive. See the link I posted.

Comment: See [this](http://powershell.org/wp/2014/02/20/powershell-gotcha-unc-paths-and-providers/) for info on using PS with UNC paths. I don't think it's your problem in this case, but it's a reason to stay away from UNC paths in PS.

Comment: Also be careful about using $ as a literal in a double quoted string. Since $ is followed by \ I think you're ok in this case, but it's better to escape it if you want to use `$` as a literal: "\\$_\C`$\blah"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you good people for your assistance.

I found a better solution, one that I can manage better - LogParser:

https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/